# learning web app development with asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have been doing windows applications using c#.
But recently our management has planned to make some of the projects to be web based.
We thought of using asp.net with c#.

Can anybody guide me on effectively learning asp.net.

pls provide some useful links for sample projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Forms would be a quicker route if your used to desktop development (over microsoft MVC). MVC3 is my preference but takes a bit longer to get used to if your not familiar with it. MVC3 gives you more control over your code and in my oppinion is less bloated.

May be worth looking into the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) if you go down this route.

Loads of videos to get you started here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms

They have a couple of example applications you can work through: 
Web Forms: [Contoso University App](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials)
MVC: [MVC3 Starter App](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs)

Answer (score 1):

as simple as this: http://www.asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to start with ASP.Net MVC even you'll find it a bit complex in the beginning , [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) you can find a lot of tutorials and books

you can also take a look at the [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) , it is a complete project to learn ASP.Net MVC by example.

Comment: Thank you all,i am going through all the references provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would steer clear of WebForms - even though it may seem a more natural fit coming from your WinForms background, you will run into issues later on. Given that you're going to have to learn a new platform anyway, makes sense to learn MVC and get off on the right foot (note that there are alternative MVC frameworks to ASP.NET MVC such as Fubu but these are probably riskier options in your situation).

[PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/find.aspx?f=mvc&olt=true&h=true) do some good online training courses, though you do need to pay for them.